# Open other ports more than HTTP & HTTPS in Traefik Kubernetes Ingress

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, traefik, traefik-ingress

I've gotten up Traefik as an Ingress in Kubernetes with this configuration: https://github.com/RedxLus/traefik-simple-kubernetes/tree/master/V1.7

And works well to HTTP and HTTPS but I don't know how can open others ports to forward, for example, a Pod with an Ingress with MySQL in port 3306

Thanks for every answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traefik doesn't support it if you are using an Ingress resource and that resource doesn't support L4 type of traffic like mentioned in the other answer.

But if you are using an Nginx ingress controller there is a workaround, use a ConfigMap with the ingress controller options `--tcp-services-configmap` and `--udp-services-configmap` as described [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services/). Then your `tcp-services` ConfigMap would look something like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: tcp-services
  namespace: ingress-nginx
data:
  9000: "default/example-go:8080"
```

The advantage of this is having a single entry point to your cluster (this applies to any ingress that would be used for TCP/UDP) but the downside is overhead of having an extra layer compared to just simply having a Kubernetes [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) (NodePort or LoadBalancer) that already listens on TCP/UDP ports.

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes Ingress API does not support it. But it is possible to use Traefik as [TCP proxy](https://docs.traefik.io/v2.0/routing/routers/#configuring-tcp-routers) for your desired use-case, but only, if you make use of TLS encrypted connections. Otherwise, based on the level 4 protocol, it's not possible to distinguish between the different hostnames and you would have to use one entrypoint per TCP router. Check this [issue](https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/4981) in GitHub.